# TS2694 (TS) Namespace 'angular' has no exported member 'ui'

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angular-ui-router, typescript-typings

After reviewing similar questions and attempting their solutions I am still at a lose as to why this scenario will not resolve.

1. Double checked for any typos
2. Attempted solution from [Q&A 45791412](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45791412/cant-find-inline-index-d-ts-of-uirouter-angularjs)
3. Examined my `yarn.lock` file for issue from [Q&A 46666667](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46666667/error-ts2694-namespace-angular-has-no-exported-member-xxx-after-upgrading)
4. Searched for answers within Github for [UIRouter](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/) found [issue 3514](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/3514) but the solution did not resolve my issue

#### Issue

Errors when building and no intellisense is being provided when applying types to UIRouter objects.

```
TS2694 (TS) Namespace 'angular' has no exported member 'ui'
TS2307 (TS) Cannot find module '@uirouter/core
```

#### Project Details

```
Node       - 8.9.4 
NPM        - 5.6.0
Yarn       - 1.3.2
Typescript - 2.6.2 (installed globally)
```

TS2694 occurs in my code when attempting to create a route definition for my module.

```
function Configuration(
    $stateProvider: ng.ui.IStateProvider
) {
    $stateProvider
        .state('Home', <ng.ui.IState>{
            url: '/',
            controller: 'HomeController',
            controllerAs: 'vm',
            templateUrl: 'js/views/home/home.html'
        });
}
```

TS2307 occurs in the index.d.ts file, only when being viewed. (reduced for brevity), it also occurs in other files with the same reference.

```
import './viewScroll';
declare const _default: "ui.router";
export default _default;
import * as core from '@uirouter/core';
export { core };
export * from '@uirouter/core';
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5", 
    "module": "commonjs", 
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true, 
    "moduleResolution": "node" 
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

npm package file (contents of devDependencies) all of these show up in my `node_modules` folder as expected.

```
"devDependencies": {
  "@types/angular": "^1.6.40",
  "@types/requirejs": "^2.1.31",
  "@uirouter/angularjs": "^1.0.13",
  "@uirouter/core": "^5.0.14",
  "angular": "^1.6.8",
  "bootstrap": "3.3.7",
  "jquery": "^3.2.1",
  "node-sass": "^4.7.2"
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I removed `node_modules` folder and reinstalled ui-router and it did the trick. 
I had the same problem as yours and the other solutions didn't work for me either. Hope it helps you.

```
rm -rf node_modules
npm i -S @uirouter/angularjs
npm i
```

Comment: This does not solve the issue, every project I try to include @ui-router/angularjs seems to have this problem.